# Simplify series of exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to simplify the following series:

1.$$\sum_{n=1,odd}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(-an^2)}{(b-n^2)^2}$$

2.$$\sum_{n=2,even}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(-an^2)}{(b-n^2)^2}$$

with $a$ and $b$ $\in \mathbf{R}^+$

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you would tell us more about where you got the problem, why you are interested in a solution, and/or what you have tried.